# How do I delete text between 2 strings?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editing, string-manipulation

I have tried the regex expression `.a href.*?..a.` and `.a href[^:]++..a.`

I want to replace `.a href=.u.gogogo98. class=.3t5uN8xUmg0TOwRCOGQEcU rel=noopener nofollow ugc target=.blank..u.gogogo98..a.` with a blank space - especially deleting the url code from the text.. eliminate everything between `.a href` and `..a.`

I have searched the regex expressions for that but both of these don't work :(

Comment: Literal periods `.` should be escaped in your regex, so something like this: `\.a href.*\.\.a`

Comment: Thanks dude, that works :)

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, a period `.` indicates 'any character'. If you want to search for a literal `.` it should be escaped by placing a backslash `\` in front of it.

The regular expression in this case would be something like `\.a href.*\.\.a\.`, meaning:

`.a href`, followed by zero or more arbitrary characters (`.*`), followed by `..a.`